# iOS Transmitting iOS library music to multiple iOS devices

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I would like to grab an audio file from the iOS device's iTunes library, then transmit it via bluetooth to another iOS device.  At that point, the audio would be playing from device #1 and device #2 at the same time.  Is this possible?  If so, where can I go to learn about how to do this?  If it is possible, can I do it using GameCenter or Airplay?

Comment: Hi. I have 2 questions for you. 1. Are you able to share music from one device to multiple devices. 2. What is estimated time to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is entirely possible, the [eavesdrop](http://www.chocomoko.com/eavesdrop) app does it.

What you'll probably need to do to get the songs is use the Media Player framework to get access to the songs you want (probably with a [picker view](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPickerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008215)), and then bring them into the AVFoundation framework as AVAssets. This can be done by using the [MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008211) key from an MPMediaItem and [`+[AVAsset assetWithURL:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009508). From there you'll have to check the exportable flag on the AVAsset, and if it is true you can use an [AVAssetExportSession](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetExportSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVAssetExportSession) to get it into your app's directory. Not entirely knowing what you plan to do you might actually be able to stop at the AVAsset and somehow work from there.

As a note, I haven't ever done any of this so don't get to mad if it doesn't work, but this is my understanding of it. Hope it helps!

Comment: eavesdrop only allows one device to connect at a time.  I could easily do that with airplay. But are you suggesting that I can circumvent airplay by using the methods above, and then use game center to stream to the multiple devices?

Comment: Eavesdrop doesn't use AirPlay as far as I know. It probably uses bonjour or GK given how it's connections work (It's worth noting that GK uses bonjour internally). As I said I'm not sure of the full implementation it would require but you can access media files through this method. How you intend to share them is something different. So yes.

Answer (score 1):

You **can** send almost everything you want through the GameKit Framework. But you **can't** access the files in your iPod Library, this means you **can't** send iPod-Songs through the GameKit Framework.

Comment: mavrick3, how is it that people are able to send their ipod music via bluetooth to external speakers? Also, some people are able to store iPod songs as data (like Sprd the Note) and transfer it to another device... so there must be SOME way of accessing the music library right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. The best way implement this is to use [MultipeerConnectivity](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/_index.html) framework. It's main appropriation is to allow apps to exchange custom data "peer to peer", including text messages, files and streamed data. The exchange is possible between multiple iOS devices, via bluetooth or wifi.

The only thing you should take into account is that that framework is first appeared on iOS7, so if you need to support an older version of iOS you should use another approaches, for example networking through [GameKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GameKit_Collection/_index.html) or [CoreBluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html). Obviously they haven't been intended for such usage and thereby this is not an easy way. Both of them don't support streams, and CoreBluetooth is developed for Low Energy Bluetooth communication, so it's bandwidth is limited. But you still can try to implement things you need using this technologies, although it's not the best way.

As about getting data from the device iPod library (iTunes media library), you can use either [AVAssetReader](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetReader_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get audio data or [AVAssetExportSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetExportSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get a full audio file into your app's sandbox. You initialize any of them with [AVURLAsset](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVURLAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html). And to create that [AVURLAsset](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVURLAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can use URL retrieved from [MPMediaPickerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaPickerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)'s [MPMediaItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) using the [MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) key.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can do it using GameCenter. Connection over bluetooth is simple, there is sample code for that.

Comment: He meant accessing the iPod-Songs, that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in android

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=play.Together

not only two devices - there is no limit on the number of phones playing

Play song together with all other cell phones. The more users playing the louder the music will be heard.

that what you meant rigth?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are asking about iOS, not Android.